# Can not login in the control panel: Internal Server Error 500

Tags: control-panel, login

The website ist working, but I can not login in the control panel.

In the console:

```
500 Internal Server Error - .../resources/lib/jquery-2.2.4.min.js?d=1493300895
setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be integer, float given (/html/alte gerberei/craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:1514)
```

...

Has anybody an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I visit the default Craft CP URL at http://ag.lovelybits.de/admin, I get the following Twig error: `Variable "entry" does not exist in "_layout" at line 23`.

Screenshot: https://cl.ly/1F3v3e3I3721

Comment: @AndreaDeMers they have a custom cp url, so naturally "admin" is just an entry(which doesn't exist) on their site. This error would not be related to their issue.

Comment: @AbbeyDesign Indeed they do: http://ag.lovelybits.de/lovelyCP. If there is a custom CP URL, is it normal to get a Twig error when pointing to the default? Wouldn't a 404 make more sense?

Comment: @AndreaDeMers well they've got other issues with their templates and how they are handling their 404's but I doubt it's related to their original problem. I suspect a bad upload of files or permissions. Something is not updated or missing.

Comment: Try downloading a fresh copy of Craft from https://craftcms.com and replacing your existing `craft/app` folder with the fresh one and see if that helps.

Comment: @BradBell I've remove the app folder and copy a new one, but the same issue.

Comment: @AndreaDeMers As AbbeyDesign mentioned, I have a custom cp url (lovelyCP). It is a early stage of development, but now you get a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the configuration in general.php, which works fine local and on three other websites.

For production environment, I added

```
'userSessionDuration' => 'P101Y',
'rememberedUserSessionDuration' => 'P101Y',
'rememberUsernameDuration' => 'P101Y',
'invalidLoginWindowDuration' => 'P101Y',
```

Now I removed it and can login in the cp - no idea why.